# Does a $ [[23,1,9]] $ code exist?

Tags: error-correction

The $ [[23,1,7]] $ Golay code is an excellent code. It is a doubly even CSS code with $ H_X=H_Z $ and allows transversal implementation of all Clifford gates.

One way in which it is not optimal is that it can only correct $ 3 $ errors ( i.e. $ d=7 $ ). However [existing linear programming bounds](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608006) suggest that with $ n=6t-1 $ qubits it is possible to correct $ t $ errors . So $ n=23 $ is the first number of qubits for which it may be possible to correct $ 4 $ errors ( i.e. $ d=9 $).

That leads to my question: Does a $ [[23,1,9]] $ code exist?

Comment: Have you looked at this website: http://www.codetables.de/ I generally find it's pretty good at the best-known limits (or was last time I checked, which was admittedly a while ago). It reports pretty much what you say - distance 8/9 codes have not been ruled out, but the best known is distance 7.